# Matching on a tuple key in an array on a mongo document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

**Background**

I have a collection of items. Here is one:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d3e315975132b3a43149225"),
"thetime" : 201812,
"name": "watermelon",
"cost" : 7,
"info" : "empty"
"taglist" : [ 
  { "color" : "red" }, 
  { "color": "green"},
  { "store" : "market" },
  { "taste" : "sweet" } ]
}
```

I am trying to do an aggregate with a `$match` on every item that has the key `color` in its `taglist` (at least once). Later I want to group on total cost of every color or every store etc. So, my output for just this item collection would be `(red: $7, green: $7)`. Point is: I don't want to use `$find`; I want to use `$match`.

**Question:**

How do I match on a tuple key in an array?

**What I have so far**

This query works for getting items that have the key value pair: (color, red):  `db.items.aggregate([{$match: {"taglist":{"color":"red"}}}]);`

But, I do not know how to change the query to return all the items with any color.

Note: I'd prefer to not start with an `$unwind` because the documents can actually be larger than this one and performance is important.

Comment: `db.items.aggregate([{$match: {"taglist.color":$exists:true}}]);`
What I understood is you want every item that has key color in its taglist. `$exist` should work for you.

Comment: I had also got the same answer https://mongoplayground.net/p/GBG8WppIGDQ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to return all the data that has the key color.
You can use `$exist`

```
db.items.aggregate([{$match: {"taglist.color":{$exists:true}}}])
```

Answer (score 2):

Before match you need to unwind taglist

```
    db.items.aggregate([
       {
          $unwind: "$taglist"
       },
       { 
          $match: { $exists:{"$taglist.color":true}}}
       }
    }
  ]);
```

On the basis of key you can group further